# How to change bottom navigation icons on selection

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

How to change bottom navigation icons on selection and unselection
This was my previous code

```
bottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bottom_tabs));
bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#FFFFFE");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First you have to make drawable selectable in your drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_icon"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_icon" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_icon" />
</selector>
```

**In the bottom navigation menu place this selectable drawable as icon**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemId"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawable_selectable_name"
        android:title="@string/title"/>
</menu>
```

**In activity or fragment where you have used bottom navigation use the following line**

```
bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = null
```